# Is it possible to @inheritParams from a function within another package?

Tags: r, documentation, roxygen2

I wrote an importer for an obscure TSV format, which I want to package and document: https://github.com/katrinleinweber/MWX-import/commits/package

The importer function passes a renamed `skip_lines` parameter to  `utils::read.table` so I would like to "pass" the latter's documentation of `skip` into my `.Rd`. However, trying a few notations like `@inheritParams utils::read.table skip` always results in `Warning: Failed to find topic […]`.

Whether it's actually possible to inherit a *single, specific* parameter from another package's function is not clear to me after reading http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/man.html and https://blog.rstudio.org/2017/02/01/roxygen2-6-0-0/.

Is it possible? If yes, thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 17):

If you use `@inheritParams utils::read.table`, then any parameters in your function which match those in `utils::read.table` will be inherited (provided they aren't already explicitly documented). So this would cover your use case if you used `skip` instead of `skip_lines`.

I don't think it's possible to inherit documentation for a parameter when your parameter name doesn't match though.

Comment: Worth noting that the prefix `utils::` must be specified: `@inheritParams read.table` will fail, even if `read.table` is loaded and in the NAMESPACE.