# Using roxygen2 to inherit only certain parameters

Tags: r, roxygen2

In roxygen2, one can use the tag `@inheritParams` to inherit the full set of parameters of another function. But is it also possible to inherit only a certain *subset* of them? (Excluding the case of inheriting `...`, which is adequately handled by `@inheritDotParams`.)

Comment: I think this question is related to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47782004/how-to-use-inheritparams-on-single-parameters-when-multiple-parameters-match) and also to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42703052/is-it-possible-to-inheritparams-from-a-function-within-another-package).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use @inheritParams on single parameters when multiple parameters match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47782004/how-to-use-inheritparams-on-single-parameters-when-multiple-parameters-match)

Answer (score 23):

In the header of `functionA`:

`@inheritParams functionB`, at least in Roxygen 6.0.0., will only inherit the parameters from `functionA` that also are found in `functionB`.  Any parameters that are shared but that are defined in the `functionA` header will not be inherited from `functionB`.

So, the selection is built-in.