# How to use @inheritParams on single parameters when multiple parameters match?

Tags: r, devtools, roxygen2

I would like to document an R function and inherit individual parameter documentation from other functions when multiple parameter names match. For example, lets say I have the following 2 functions.

```
#' Function 1.
#' 
#' Description of function 1.
#' 
#' @param x XYZ
#' @param y ZYX
#' @return Numeric
fun1 <- function(x, y) {value <- 1}

#' Function 2.
#' 
#' Description of function 2.
#' 
#' @param x ABC
#' @param y CBA
#' @return Numeric
fun2 <- function(x, y) {value <- 2}
```

I now want to create a third function that inherits parameter x from fun1 and parameter y from fun2. The following do not work:

```
#' Function 3.
#'
#' Description of function 3.
#'
#' @inherit fun1 params x
#' @inherit fun2 params y
fun3 <- function(x, y) {value <- 3}

#' Function 3.
#'
#' Description of function 3.
#'
#' @inheritParams fun1 x
#' @inheritParams fun2 y
fun3 <- function(x, y) {value <- 3}
```

If you do the following then both parameters are inherited from fun1:

```
#' Function 3.
#'
#' Description of function 3.
#'
#' @inheritParams fun1
#' @inheritParams fun2
fun3 <- function(x, y) {value <- 3}
```

I'm not sure what else to try or if this is even possible?

Answer (score 14):

You can use `roxygen2` templates for parameters too:

- Create a folder called `man-roxygen`.
- Add it to `.Rbuildignore` by appending a line with `^man-roxygen`.
- Inside that folder you can create R files with documentation snippets.
  For instance, let's say you have a file `x-arg.R` with:

  - `#' @param x My x parameter.`
- In all the functions where you want to use the same documentation snippet,
  write `@template x-arg` instead of `@param bla bla`.
- Profit.

EDIT: also, you can have more than one `@param` entry per template if it fits your use case.

I believe this works for pretty much any kind of documentation you want to repeat,
though some cases require special handling.
For example, if you wanted to have a template with some text that should go under a specific section (e.g. "Details"),
the snippet in the R template file must also have the corresponding directive,
and then to use it you might need to repeat the directive if you have additional specific text:

In `details-template.R`

```
#' @details
#'
#' Text that should appear everywhere
```

To use it

```
#' @details
#'
#' Some specific text.
#'
#' @template details-template
```

Comment: Apparently the preferred way to do this now is `@eval` rather than creating the `man-roxygen` directory and using `@template` https://github.com/r-lib/usethis/issues/1617#issuecomment-1085204078