# Is there an automatic way to include executed code in an .rd file?

Tags: r, documentation

I would like to automatically generate documentation for my R functions and I've already come across the package roxygen2, which almost fulfills my needs.
However, I would like to include in my documentation whole chunks of code without having to enclose them with #' '''. Practically speaking, in the example below I would like to automatically include

```
add <- function(x, y) {
  x + y
}
```

in my "sum.rd" file as it is (i.e., without having to duplicate it in file "sum.R" and enclose it in #' ''').

Is there any way to achieve this?

---

file "sum.R":

```
#' Add together two numbers \
#' @param x A number \
#' @param y A number \
#' @return The sum of \code{x} and \code{y} \
#' @examples \
#' add(1, 1) \
#' add(10, 1) \
add <- function(x, y) { \
  x + y \
}
```

Comment: You probably could use a template like described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57101578/9349302). However, you would still need to wrap the function in `#'` in the template itself, so this won't be your desired solution, I guess.

Comment: Might be better to put it in a vignette and then just reference that in the help file.